# Haskell constructor ">>="meaning?

Tags: haskell

```
>>=
>>= what is this mean in the Haskell programming?
uncurry meaning?
```

what is meaning of >>= in the Haskell programming?
  what is uncurry mean in Haskell?

Comment: uncurry is not related to `>>=`. See https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:uncurry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`>>=` is a function name, not a constructor name. Constructor names in Haskell have to start with a capital letter or a colon (`:`).

In the Prelude `>>=` is defined as a method of `class Monad m` as follows:

```
(>>=) :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

This called the "bind operator" and meant to combine a value of a monad with a function that uses the value "contained" in the monad.

For the `IO` monad `action1 >>= \value -> action2` executes `action1`, feeds the result of the action into the function and then executes `action2`.

For the list monad `>>=` is equivalent to `concatMap`, that is it executes the given function for each element of the given list and produces the concattenation of the thus-produced lists as its result.

The special thing about `>>=` is that it's used by the desugaring of the `do` notation. So `a >>= \b -> c` can also be written using `do` notation like this:

```
do
  b <- a
  c
```

So by defining `>>=` for your type (via a `Monad` instance), you control how `do` notation behaves for your type.

Comment: so can I rewrite    action1 >>= \value -> action2   without  >>=  just use some simply function

Comment: @Joe Yes, every use of `>>=` (or `>>`) is equivalent to `do` notation (and vice versa).

Comment: Can I rewrite action2 ([a],[b]@(_:_)) = action1 ([a'],[b']) >>= action1   to   action2([a],[b]@(_:_)) = action2(action1([a'],[b'])) Just like what you said first executes action1 and feed the result to the function which is in action2 and then execute action2. So can I regard  action2 (a,b) = action1 (a',b') >>= action1  just like recursion in this case, because i will not stop execute action1 and 2 many times until it meets the trivial case which is when [b] becomes empty list.

Answer (score 0):

The operation is called bind and from the [haskell tutorial docs](https://www.haskell.org/tutorial/monads.html)

> The bind operations, >> and >>=, combine two monadic values (...)

I suggest reading the link above - it's well explained there